# I'm trying to count items in an array and it returning less

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php

public function fetchitems()
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $this->tablename";

    $result = mysqli_query($this->conn, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        return $result;
    } else {
        die("error returned nothing");
    }

    $count = count(($result);
    echo $count

?>
```

The variable `$result` holds data from database where I have 8 products but I'm getting count 5 when I run. How do I fix this

Comment: There are quite a few syntax errors in this code so not sure what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code may this help you:-

```
$result = mysqli_query($this->conn, $sql);
$num_rows = mysqli_fetch_row($result)[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have quite a few syntax errors, I'm happy to walk through them if you drop a comment.

Anyway, try this, let me know if you have any other errors

You biggest problem is not correctly returning the count. I haven't tested the following, but plug and play - see what comes up next:

```
<?php

    public function fetchitems()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM $this->tablename";

        $result = mysqli_query($this->conn, $sql);
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if (empty($count)){
            die("error returned nothing");
            // suggest:
            // return false;
            // or
            // return 0;
        }

        return $count;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Not sure if `die()` is the appropriate way to deal with not finding a record.

Comment: I agree, I didn't want to change his code beyond recognition. I'd recommend a boolean result instead `return false`

Comment: will this help me find the number of items returned?